# Web Scraper: Why am I getting AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'?

Tags: python

I'm making my first web scraper which is supposed to return the S&P 500 Index from bloomberg.com, however when I try to run it I get this error message: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'.

The code I used as reference (from https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-scrape-websites-with-python-and-beautifulsoup-5946935d93fe/) used urllib2, which I learned has been split up into multiple libraries. So I am not sure if this is the issue?

```
  from urllib.request import urlopen
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

  url = 'https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/SPX:IND'

  htmlpage = urlopen(url)

  soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlpage, 'html.parser')

  name_box = soup.find('h1', attrs={'class':'name'})

  name = name_box.text.strip(0)
  print(name)

  price_box = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'price'})
  price = price_box.text
  print(price)
```

It should return S&P 500 Index from bloomberg.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the elements you're trying to find were not found.
You can check that by commenting

```
name = name_box.text.strip(0)
price = price_box.text
```

And verifying the values of `name` and `price`

Also, make sure you check the HTML in `soup` so you make sure the request was successful and the elements you want are available.